# Git graph with ref logs

Tags: git

I am trying to improve my custom git log format string. I have almost everything I want except the ref names. I can already get a log similar to what I want:

```
> git log --all --source --pretty=oneline --graph

* b7c7ad3855b54e94ad7ac03f2d2e5b96d6e5ac1d      refs/heads/b1 na
| *   695e1482622a79230fa1d83afb8d70e86847334a  refs/heads/master Merge branch 'b1'
| |\  
| |/  
|/|   
* | ec21f370f82096c0208f43b390da234d92e8c74a    refs/heads/b1 beta
* | c6bc1f55ab3b1bd568493a5de4298dfcb4f66d8d    refs/heads/b1 alfa
* | 762dd868ae87753afc1cbf9803744c76f9a9e121    refs/heads/b1 tango
| * 57fb27bff06ee9bb569f93ba815e9dcd69521c13    refs/heads/master little last post commit
|/  
| * 8d613d09b43152a7263b6e02d47ec8a4304f54be    refs/heads/b3 the other commit
| * e1f32b7cb86633351df06e37c2c58ef3f9fafc40    refs/heads/b3 something
|/  
| * 01b5c6728cf25dd576733211ce75dd3ecc29c7ba    refs/heads/b2 this time a
```

I am fighting to get a customized output with my own format string like this:

```
>  git log --pretty=format:'%h - %gD %s' --source -g        
b7c7ad3 - HEAD@{0} na
ec21f37 - HEAD@{1} beta
01b5c67 - HEAD@{2} this time a
01b5c67 - HEAD@{3} this time a
695e148 - HEAD@{4} Merge branch 'b1'
57fb27b - HEAD@{5} little last post commit
```

My main problem is that I cannot get the ref names I want. I assume it is one of the %g? format strings, but none of them seem to give me the full ref name.

Another problem is that the %g? format strings are empty unless I walk the reflogs (-g). However git refuses to combine --graph with -g

How can reproduce the first sample with a format string which I can further customize?

Comment: I’m pretty sure that’s not possible

Comment: @Chronial, even if it is not possible, just out of curiosity, could you explain why is it not possible to print the very same log, just with a different format?

Comment: I actually looked at the sourcecode :). And I didn’t do a full sweep, but the function for displaying these refs seems only to be called when you use one of the built in formats.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. Just use `%d` and provide `--decorate=full`

```
$ git log --pretty=format:'%h %d'
bde5d58  (HEAD, origin/master, master)
dd4446d 
1eeab2a 
...

$ git log --decorate=full --pretty=format:'%h %d'
bde5d58  (HEAD, refs/remotes/origin/master, refs/heads/master)
dd4446d 
1eeab2a 
...
```

Comment: I am afraid that is not the solution. Look at my first example. Every commit shows the ref/branch where it belongs. Your proposed solution does for only some commits.